# Firebase Authentication using createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("asdljhasd@gmail.com","asdasd2123")
                .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            //finally, the user is registered!
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congratulations! you have been registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I'm stuck in the progress dialog and it doesn't register anything on authentication.

Comment: Are you sure you have a network connection? That seems the most likely reason for the call never completing.

Comment: yeah i have, one other thing is when i tried to run it on my device, it says register fail.

Comment: That error message will typically also say *why* registration failed. Please include the entire error message in your question if you need further help.